# Calling to function code error in else statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

when I use the code like this I got error that in compile time that expression statement is not assigment or call... (inside the else statment)

What I miss here to make it work ?i've tried to play with the bracktes without success:(
I new to JS/Jquery ...

***The error is inside the else statment...***

> error: errorCreation, dataType: "json";

```
  function create() {
......

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Users")',
                data: postData,
                success: function(result) {


                    if (data.ErrorMsg == null) {
                        // success
                    } else {
                        // error msg

                        error: errorCreation,
                        dataType: "json";



                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        };
```

Comment: ajax has a callback for handling error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Users")',
    data: postData,
    success: function (result) {
       if (data.ErrorMsg != null) {
          // success stuff
       } else {
          errorCreation(); // do you want this function to run here?
          // error message stuff
       }
    },
    error: errorCreation, // or here?
    dataType: "json"
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajax